# concatenate features from different steps in sklearn Pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn

I want to cascade 4 steps in a pipeline to build a supervised classifier:
(1) dimension reduction with PCA, obtaining a matrix_1 of s rows (samples) by c columns (components).

(2) feed the output matrix_1 from (1) to a KMeans blind separation, obtaining a matrix_2 of s rows (samples) by 1 column (group label).

(3) horizontally concatenate matrix_1 from (1) and matrix_2 from (2), obtaining a matrix_3 of s rows (samples) by c+1 columns (c components plus 1 label).

(4) feed the output matrix_3 from (3) to a neural network of MLPClassifier.

So my pipeline will look like this:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('step1', PCA()), ('step2', KMeans()), ('step3', myStep3(FastICA().components_, KMeans().labels_)), ('step4', MLPClassifier())])
```

Now my question is how to realized the 'step3' in the pipeline. Is there a sklearn function/class for me to replace "myStep3()"?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to duplicate your feature columns and apply a separate transformer to each. The first group would be getting the PCA transformation only, the second group would be getting the PCA and KMeans. This can be achieved using `ColumnTransformer` which assigns different transformations to different sets of columns. On a dummy example, it would look like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

#Generate dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.random.random(100), "b": np.random.random(100), "y": np.random.choice(2,100)})

#Duplicate columns ["a", "b"] into ["a_new", "b_new"]
cols = ["a", "b"]
new_cols = [col_name + "_new" for col_name in cols]
df[new_cols] = df[cols]

#"cols" are receiving only the PCA
#"new_cols" are receiving a Pipeline made of PCA and KMeans
CT = ColumnTransformer([("onlyPCA", PCA(), cols),
                        ("PCA+KMeans", Pipeline([("PCA", PCA()), ("KMeans", KMeans())]), new_cols)])

#Wrap the whole thing into a Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([("transformer", CT), ("classifier", MLPClassifier())])

pipe.fit(df[cols+new_cols], df.y)
```

Note that then you would also need to do duplicate the data in the predict step:

```
pipe.predict(df[cols+new_cols])
```

Answer (score 1):

MaximeKan's answer is fantastic. I approached it in a different route using `FeatureUnion`, which can avoid the column duplication.

```
Pipeline(steps=[('ftrUn', FeatureUnion([('myDr', PCA()),('myDrKm', Pipeline([('myDr', PCA()),('myKM', KMeans())]))])),('myNN', MLPClassifier())])
```

The only issue here (also applies to the MaximeKan's above), is the output of KMeans().fit_transform(). This output are sample-center distance, rather than my original request of cluster labels.

Comment: To get cluster labels, consider a custom class inheriting from `KMeans` but overriding `transform(self, X)` as just `return self.predict(X)`?  You could also maybe use one of the `Stacking` ensembles, but then you'll get some cross-validation thrown in there that maybe you don't want/need.